# erro de compilação do arduino

Tags: arduino, int

meu codigo no arduino

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 
int pinoMotor = 11; 
int pinoBotao = 12;
int on = 0;
int estadoBotao;

pinMode(pinoMotor, OUTPUT);
pinMode(pinoBotao, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 
estadoBotao = digitalRead(pinoBotao);
       if (estadoBotao == HIGH) {
            if(on == 1)
            {on = 0;}
       else{on = 1;}

}

if ( on ==1) 
     {digitalWrite (pinoMotor, HIGH);
     }
else {digitalWrite (pinoMotor, LOW);}

delay (100);
```

Bem, quando compilo esse código, na linha do comando estadoBotao = digitalRead(pinoBotao);
sai a mensagem:

> 'estadoBotao' was not declared in the scope

Comment: Declare suas 4 variáveis fora das funções. Caso contrário, só estarão acessíveis dentro da função onde foram declaradas (no caso, `setup`).

Comment: bfavaretto  fiz o que  vc comentou porem quando declaro as variaves antes do void setup, aparece uma nova msg de erro "Erro compilando para a placa Arduino Uno"